# Calling onCreateOptionsMenu manually in Android 10

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, activity-lifecycle, android-10.0

Is there any way to force framework to call my fragment's `onCreateOptionsMenu` method.
What my issue is I am doing some work in `onResume()` method which is taking some time.

```
    @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            Log.d(TAG,"onResume");
            super.onResume();
            //some work
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        Log.d(TAG,"onCreateOptionsMenu start");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE,132332,0,"ABCD").setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE,132332,0,"ABC").setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);
        Log.d(TAG,"onCreateOptionsMenu end");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

What I observed is `onCreateOptionsMenu` is called after some delay(like 1 second) after `onResume()` method is finished. This is causing a small delay in showing options menu on UI.
So, Is there any way to force framework to call my fragment's `onCreateOptionsMenu` method. I searched about it on internet but didn't find any answer.

Comment: "What my issue is I am doing some work in onResume() method which is taking some time." -- move that work to a background thread. If `onResume()` takes longer than 1ms, "you're doing it wrong".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call [invalidateOptionsMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu())

Comment: invalidateOptionsMenu() will work only when menu is created once. So it is not working. What I want is to be my options menu created early.
Once onCreateOptionMenu is called, then I can call  invalidateOptionsMenu.

Comment: The problem is that you're doing too much loading in the main thread. You should consider using an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) for that.

Comment: Don't know why my answer is being downvoted. This is really the answer to the question: `So, Is there any way to force framework to call my fragment's onCreateOptionsMenu method`. I can't help it that the real problem isn't clearly mentioned in the original question.

Comment: @VivekMangal Probably not, but it would help if you show us what you're doing in `onResume` that is taking so long.

Answer (score -1):

you should doing you long job in a backgroud thread

Comment: isn't order is onStart->onResume->onCreateOptionsMenu